# why does cypress invoke animate not working even calling?

Tags: jquery, cypress

I am new to cypress.io and trying to invoke animate function . tried searching the same on different forums but not finding any relevent answers .

As per the documentation available :

[image]

The website on which i am trying to invoke animation is https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp.

I am expecting that below code should invoke animation ( without the need to click the button )  and cypress output should like below , but in actual my test case is passing without any error but with no animation done .

Expected Output
[image]

Code :

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

context("invoke function Jquery", ()=> {

    beforeEach(()=>{
        cy.visit("https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp")
            })

    it(" Invoke & Jquery  ",()=> {
    cy.get("button#bDemo").invoke('animate')
    }
    
    )

   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

found the same , i was invoking animation on wrong element . ideally is should be on

"#divDemo") and i was invoking the same on ("button#bDemo"). Also , i was not passing parameters which was required . what a powerful tool it is :)

cy.get("#divDemo").invoke('animate',{left:"170px",opacity:"0.5"},"slow")
.invoke('animate',{fontSize:"5em"},"slow")

[image]